# Can you change flutter text theme?

Tags: flutter, material-design, flutter-web, flutter-theme

If the theme is set in main.dart as

```
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'MY APP',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    fontFamily: 'Cabin',
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      headline1: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'Raleway',
        color: Colors.black,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        fontSize: 18,
      ),
      subtitle1: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'Raleway',
        color: Colors.black54,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        fontSize: 16,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

and I'm using the theme as

```
Text('MY STRING',
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1),
```

How can I make 'MY STRING' be a different color then the subtitle1 theme color while keeping the other properties of theme data, such as font weight and family and size, etc.?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use de method `copyWith(color: your_color)` to change properties of a TextTheme.

Example:

```
Text('MY STRING',
  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1
    .copyWith(color: Colors.red),
)
```

Doc Reference: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme/copyWith.html

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you.