# Boolean controlled textstyle in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a boolean that controls the design of a container, its color, decoration, etc. based on if it is True or not. Is there a possible way for it to control the style of any text that is put into it?

Comment: Can you include your current snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can use two kind of style in extra file and switch:

```
style: isBoolean ? firstTextstyle : secondTextstyle,
```

In another file create two textstyle and  use above:

```
final firstTextstyle = Textstyle();
```

You can use theme here like [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66605498/can-you-change-flutter-text-theme)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it by creating a `TextStyle` object according to the situation.

```
bool b =true;
TextStyle t1 = TextStyle(fontSize: 10);//true TextStyle
TextStyle t2 = TextStyle(fontSize: 20);//false TextStyle
    
Text('text', style: b ? t1 : t2,);
```